# Grant all privileges on two tables to one user

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have searched the web, but can't find anything that addresses this question. I want to give all privileges on two different tables to a user. Can this be done? This is what I have.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES 
    ON TABLE SALES, PRODUCT
    TO FRED
```

Thanks!

Comment: SQL is a language. Which SQL product (DBMS) are you using?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2012.

Comment: Does it have to be done in a single statement?

Comment: It doesn't have to, I just wasn't sure if there was a more efficient way to write it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `grant` syntax handles one table at a time. Also, there is no "table" after the "on":

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON SALES TO FRED;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON PRODUCT TO FRED;
```

Comment: IIRC, "all privileges" is deprecated syntax. For a table, you'd `GRANT CONTROL` which implies the other privileges.